# while read with spaces in filenames

Tags: bash, while-loop, ffmpeg

On this `.ogg` files

```
$ tree
.
├── Disc 1 - 01 - Procrastination.ogg
├── Disc 1 - 02 - À carreaux !.ogg
├── Disc 1 - 03 - Météo marine.ogg
└── mp3
```

I try with a `while` loop to ffmpeg convert them to mp3 keeping spaces in filenames::

```
$ ls *.ogg | while read line; do ffmpeg -i "$line" mp3/"$line".mp3 ; done
```

But I get this error::

```
$ ls *.ogg | while read line; do ffmpeg -i "$line" mp3/"$line".mp3 ; done
...
Parse error, at least 3 arguments were expected, only 0 given
in string ' 1 - 02 - À carreaux !.ogg' ...
...
```

This report [bash ffmpeg find and spaces in filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966084/bash-ffmpeg-find-and-spaces-in-filenames) even if it look similar is for a more complicate script and has no answer.

This [ffmpeg not working with filenames that have whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766111/ffmpeg-not-working-with-filenames-that-have-whitespace) only fix it when output is a http:// URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop here; let `find` execute the command for you.

```
find . -type f -name '*.ogg' -exec ffmpeg -i {} mp3/{}.mp3 \;
```

Or, if you want to strip the `.ogg` extension from the result:

```
find . -type f -name '*.ogg' -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "$1" mp3/"${1%.ogg}.mp3"' _ {} \;
```

Conversely, you can skip `find` altogether:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in **/*.ogg; do
  [[ -f $f ]] || continue
  ffmpeg -i  "$f" mp3/"${f%.ogg}.mp3"
done
```

Comment: for your first answer, I guess that ``\;`` is missing

Comment: for the second it work's but I don't understand what is ``_ {}`` at the end

Comment: When you run `sh -c '...'`, the next argument sets the value of `$0` in the new shell. You rarely care what that value is; I use `_` as a dummy value. `{}` is the current file passed by `find`, which the shell accesses as `$1`.

Answer (score 6):

Use `find -print0` to get the NUL-separated list of files, instead of parsing `ls` output which is never a good idea:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -d '' -r file; do
  ffmpeg -i "$file" mp3/"$file".mp3 </dev/null
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.ogg' -print0)
```

You can use a simple glob to do this as well:

```
shopt -s nullglob # make glob expand to nothing in case there are no matching files
for file in *.ogg; do
  ffmpeg -i "$file" mp3/"$file".mp3
done
```

---

See:

- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: The for loop with shopt ... works very well ; but the while did not work. ffmpeg hang at the end of the first file:
"""... Output #0, mp3, to 'mp3/./Disc 1 - 02 - À carreaux !.ogg.mp3':size=     378kB time=00:00:24.16 bitrate= 128.2kbits/s speed=48.3x    
Enter command: <target>|all <time>|-1 <command>[ <argument>]
"""

Comment: @user3313834, put `</dev/null` on the `ffmpeg` line to stop it from consuming stdin.